# Remove small pause between loops in audio clip in Java

Tags: java, audio-player

I have written a function in Java that plays a .wav file and has an option to loop that clip infinitely. For some songs, I want to loop from a specific portion in the song for an uninterrupted audio file. This code nearly achieves that. However, there is a very brief pause (maybe 2-3 tenths of a second) between the end of the file and the beginning of the loop. The thread is not sleeping so I'm not sure why the pause in music is there. How can I remove this pause?

```
    public synchronized void playSound(final String url, boolean repeat, float volume, double loopAt) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                            Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + url));
                    clip.open(inputStream);
                    clip.setMicrosecondPosition((long)loopAt*1000 *1000);
                    clip.setLoopPoints(clip.getFramePosition(), -1);
                    clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
                    currentTrack = clip;
                    Music.this.setVolume(volume);
                    if (repeat == true)
                        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                    else
                        clip.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
```

Comment: since you mention "end of the file": did you make triply-sure that the file itself doesn't have a few ms of fade in/out or silence at the start and/or end?

Comment: Yes I thought of that just before posting and checked. The file ends with the waves way up.